# Searching for book about non-Euclidean geometry that recapitulates the First Book of the Elements

Tags: reference-request, geometry, euclidean-geometry

I am looking for a specific book on non-Euclidean geometry that I read in my undergraduate years.

The unique characteristic of this book is that the first part of the book started by re-proving in modern notation the entirety of the first book of Euclid's Elements – given that all the geometry up until Euclid used the parallel postulate would be common to Euclidean and non-Euclidean geometries.  The second part of the book treats a few equivalent formulations of the parallel postulate and the ways in which non-Euclidean geometry modifies them.

Comment: Do you remember when you read it? Knowing the year, one can eliminate some options. For example [Geometry: Euclid and Beyond](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-22676-7) is quite recent, while [The elements of non-Euclidean geometry](https://archive.org/details/elementsofnoneuc00sommuoft/page/viii/mode/2up) is much more older.

Comment: I have the feeling that you might be referring to Marvin J. Greenberg's "Euclideand and Non-Euclidean Geometries: Development and History": http://bibotu.com/books/2013/History%20and%20Philosophy%20of%20Science/Greenberg%20-%20Euclidean%20and%20Non-Euclidean%20Geometries%20-%20Development%20and%20History%203e%20(WHF,%201993).pdf

Comment: @JoséHdz.Stgo. You are absolutely correct!  This is precisely the book I was looking for!  Do you want to make your comment an official answer to give you credit?

Comment: @user6530 : Thank you for the reference of Geometry: Euclid and Beyond.  It looks like a very worthwhile read!

Comment: ltcomdata: I have done so! Hope you "accept" it later on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The book is none other than [Marvin Jay Greenberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvin_Greenberg)'s "Euclidean and Non-Euclidean Geometries: Development and History" (the fourth edition of which is available wherever fine books are sold).